# JavaScript is not working when using Bootstrap 5.3

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I am building a website on Visual Studio Code and I'm using Bootstrap 5.3, but the functions are not working - buttons not expanding, carousel not rolling, etc. I'm a beginner, so I've been struggling to understand why :(

Do someone know what's the issue or had the same problem?

Many thanks!

I used the CDN from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/

This is what I have in head - these are followed by my own css file only.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

*I didn't start my own JavaScript yet, only have the html and css files.

Comment: Did you reference both the css and javascript file from your html? Are you using a frontend framework?

Comment: Please edit your answer and include any relevant code/markup you've built which doesn't work. This will allow people to give you more accurate answers as right now people will be taking their best guess.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include both of the required resources. Put them both in your `<head>` element.

**The Bootstrap5 css (style) bundle**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**The Bootstrap5 JavaScript Bundle**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/

If you edit your post to contain the html itself then we can have a look and see what the issue is. This will most likely lead to better answers for you.